# What part of speech is the word 'much' in the sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Twelve minutes is not much.

In this sentence, is the word 'much' used as a pronoun or adverb?

Comment: Neither: I would say it was a 'fused' determiner-head. It combines (fuses) the function of 'determiner' and 'head' into a single word. It can be glossed as "Twelve minutes is not much time

Answer (score 1):

I think we have implicit noun: time

> Twelve minutes is not much time

and hence "not much" is playing the role of a determiner.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence uses a linking verb (is) which means the subject can accept either a Predicate Adjective or Predicate Nominative.  The Predicate Adjective is the phrase (not much).